# JavaScript regular expression: inserting span tag for each character

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regular expression task at hand and can really use some help.

Say I have a text like below:

```
To Sherlock Holmes she is always <i>THE</i> woman.
```

I need to enclose each character in a span tag, with exception of HTML tags. For example, the text above would be:

```
<span>T</span><span>o</span><span> </span><span>S</span><span>h</span>
<span>e</span><span>r</span><span>l</span><span>o</span><span>c</span>
<span>k</span><span> </span><span>H</span><span>o</span><span>l</span>
<span>m</span><span>e</span><span>s</span><span> </span><span>s</span>
<span>h</span><span>e</span><span> </span><span>i</span><span>s</span>
<span> </span><span>a</span><span>l</span><span>w</span><span>a</span>
<span>y</span><span>s</span><span> </span><i><span>T</span><span>H</span>
<span>E</span></i><span> </span><span>w</span><span>o</span><span>m</span>
<span>a</span><span>n</span><span>.</span>
```

Note that:

- each character is enclosed in a span
  tag, even a space
- HTML tag, `<i></i>` is not

Any suggestion is welcome.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you know how much markup will be present?  Specifically, do you know if you'll be dealing with nested html tags, like <b><i>awesomesauce</i></b>?  The presence of nested tags makes it a considerably harder problem.

Comment: rest assured, its not a regular expression task :)

Comment: Nested tags is quite possible, but initially we can assume no if it makes it easier.

Comment: Why do you need this? It's quite likely there's a better solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This job is better handled by DOM interactions. The following two utility functions will work help wrapping each character in the given text with a span tag.

```
/**
 * recursively get all text nodes as an array for a given element
 */
function getTextNodes(node) {
    var childTextNodes = [];

    if (!node.hasChildNodes()) {
        return;
    }

    var childNodes = node.childNodes;
    for (var i = 0; i < childNodes.length; i++) {
        if (childNodes[i].nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE) {
            childTextNodes.push(childNodes[i]);
        }
        else if (childNodes[i].nodeType == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
            Array.prototype.push.apply(childTextNodes, getTextNodes(childNodes[i]));
        }
    }

    return childTextNodes;
}

/**
 * given a text node, wrap each character in the
 * given tag.
 */
function wrapEachCharacter(textNode, tag) {
    var text = textNode.nodeValue;
    var parent = textNode.parentNode;

    var characters = text.split('');
    characters.forEach(function(character) {
        var element = document.createElement(tag);
        var characterNode = document.createTextNode(character);
        element.appendChild(characterNode);

        parent.insertBefore(element, textNode);
    });

    parent.removeChild(textNode);
}
```

Now given some piece of HTML, we will create a DOM representation of it, and then retrieve all text nodes from it using the first function - `getTextNodes`. Once we have all the text nodes, we can pass each one of them to the second function - `wrapEachCharacter`.

```
// create a wrapper element that will hold our HTML.
var container = document.createElement('div');
container.innerHTML = "To Sherlock Holmes she is always <i>THE</i> woman.";

// get all text nodes recursively.
var allTextNodes = getTextNodes(container);

// wrap each character in each text node thus gathered.
allTextNodes.forEach(function(textNode) {
    wrapEachCharacter(textNode, 'span');
});
```

An example is posted [here](http://jsfiddle.net/anurag/R72ha/).

Comment: Thanks @Anurag, your solution provides the best result! It works with nested tags as well. :)

Answer (score 4):

Something along this line should do the trick

```
txt = txt.replace (/(<.*?>)|(.)/g, function (m0, tag, ch) {
   return tag || ('<span>' + ch + '</span>');
});
```

Comment: this is close to what I wanted, but Anurag's DOM manipulation provides additional benefits. Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a regex, just loop over the string using a for loop:

```
var s = 'To Sherlock Holmes she is always <i>THE</i> woman.';
var out = '';
for (var z = 0; z < s.length; ++z) {
    var ch = s.charAt(z);
    if (ch == '<') {
        while (ch != '>') {
            out += ch;
            ch = s.charAt(++z);
        }
        out += ch;
        continue;
    }
    out += '<span>' + ch + '</span>';
}
alert(out);
```

Comment: Thanks for your input @Lee. I went with DOM manipulation instead.

Comment: @Gmbeagle - Just out of curiosity, what did you find was the benefit of the "DOM manipulation" method?  The approach I've shown here works (even with nested tags), the code is concise, and it should perform substantially better than a DOM-based approach.