# Jquery Click onto single Character?

Tags: jquery

I have a div that contains different characters (utf emoticons to be precise)

I now need a function do detect a click on a **single** element

```
<div class="optIcons">️❤️</div>
```

I can detect a click on the div:

```
 $(document).on('click','.optIcons', function() {}
```

But I need to find out *which* character has been clicked either by attaching an event on every single character *or* by being able to detect which one has been clicked from the div-Event.

Is this possible or do I have to wrap each character into another span?

Comment: The simplest way is to wrap each character in a span. It may well be possible to detect a click on individual characters in a textNode, but it's not going to be fun writing the code to do that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I detect onclick() or similar for individual characters in a text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9531149/how-can-i-detect-onclick-or-similar-for-individual-characters-in-a-text)

Comment: Try [Grapheme-Splitter library](https://github.com/orling/grapheme-splitter) to work with emoji. But still as our friends here suggested, you need to wrap each character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a `<b/>` tag simply because it "bloats" the code way less than a separate span tag (and does not seem to have any effect on emoticons):

```
<span class="optIcons"><b></b><b></b><b></b><b></b><b>️❤️</b><b>️</b><b></b><b></b></span>

$(document).on('click','.optIcons b', function() {
  console.log(this.textContent);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

you can put every character in span with specific Id like this example:

```js
$("#exp1").click(function(){alert('')});
```

```html
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="optIcons"><span id='exp1'></span>️❤️</div>
```